# How to acquire multiple locks without ordering constraints in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

So I have code similar to this

```
synchronized(objectOne){ do stuff }
synchronized(objectTwo){ do stuff }
```

The problem with this is the program will wait for the lock on `objectOne`, even if the lock for `objectTwo` is available. What I'm trying to do is say: try to lock both `objectOne` and `objectTwo`, and whichever lock you get first do the stuff for that lock. I've come up with a solution but I think it's rather hacky and I'm wondering if anybody has any better ideas.

Here's my idea: Start 2 threads, each one waiting on a lock and then the main thread will wait on a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). So you end up with something like this:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

new Thread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
    synchronized(objectOne) { do stuff }
    latch.countDown();
}).start();

new Thread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
    synchronized(objectTwo) { do stuff }
    latch.countDown();
}).start();

latch.await();
```

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach to me.

Comment: I cant tell by the code posted, but in my experience, a class that locks on two different objects should almost always be split into two classes, with the locking encapsulated **inside** the two classes, not by the class that aggregates them

Comment: you are using two different locks so the thread B may not see the memory changes by the thread A, I suspect there will be no happens-before here.

Comment: also it's not clear why you can't implement an ordering policies, for example order the lock acquiring by their System.identityHashCode() values to avoid deadlocking.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should use [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) which provides you with the method [`boolean tryLock()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock%28%29).

> Returns:
>           true if the lock was acquired and false otherwise

Proceed with do stuff when you have at least one of the locks.

Comment: So are you suggesting something like repeatedly trying both locks until you get either one, encapsulated by some busy waiting loop?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have 2 queues of jobs, 2 threads each polling a queue and execute the jobs.

For jobs related to objectOne, you put it in queue#1; jobs related to objectTwo in queue#2.

```
worker1.queue.put( new Runnable(){ public void run() { do stuff } } );
worker2.queue.put( new Runnable(){ public void run() { do stuff } } );

----

class Worker extends Thread

    BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public void run()
        while(true)
            queue.take().run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the amount of `stuff` it could be more overhead to spin off multiple threads to do stuff. It might just be best to do stuff in a single thread if `stuff` is a fast enough operation. You will have to time it to know.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of like your hack, at least if it's a one-off situation.  That said...

If you're doing this sort of thing a lot and want something "less hacky", I'd suggest [ExecutorService#invokeAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29).  This takes a list of Callables, executes them on a thread pool and blocks until they're all done.

Sketch:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); // for example...
List<Future<Void>> results = es.invokeAll(new ArrayList {{ 
        add(new Callable<Void> { 
            public Void call() { synchronized(objectOne) { do stuff } }
        });
        add(new Callable<Void> { 
            public Void call() { synchronized(objectTwo) { do stuff } }
        });
    }});
// both Callables are done when you get here
```

This obviously assumes that it's ok to call these methods from different threads at this point in your app.  If for some reason you need to call both from the same thread, I think you're doomed to use `tryLock` and busy-wait as discussed in Bhesh Gurung's answer.